# How to exclude rows with a duplicate column value and sort results by list of IDs before removing duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to this:

```
----------------------------------
| id    |   user_id   |  likes   |
----------------------------------
|  1    |      1      |  dogs    | 
|  2    |      1      |  cats    | 
|  3    |      2      |  fish    | 
|  4    |      2      |  snakes  | 
|  5    |      1      |  pandas  | 
|  6    |      1      |  fish    | 
----------------------------------
```

I have a list of `id`s I will use to retrieve the rows, but I only want to return one row per user (the `id`s correspond to rows for multiple users). The list will only be some of the `ids` in the table, not all of them. For example:

```
2,1,3,6
```

If more than one of the `id`s in the list belongs to the same user, I would like to retrieve the row for the `id` appearing first in the list.

In the example above, row with `id` = 2 should be returned for `user_id` 1 and row with `id` = 3 should be returned for `user_id` 2.

I can use `GROUP BY` without an aggregate:

```
SELECT id, user_id, likes
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (2,1,3,6)
GROUP BY user_id
```

But from what I've read doing that is semantically incorrect. This also doesn't return the row for the `id` appearing first in the list, but instead appears to return the row with the lowest `id` (so row with `id` = 1 is returned for `user_id` 1, when I would like to get row with `id` = 2). I tried adding `ORDER BY FIELD` to the query, but it appears this takes place after the grouping.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Not very clear....
So, for user 1 you have ids 2,1,3
What about user 2? You will have different set of IDs, and you want to receive at the end both user 1 and user 2, each with its first record from given list?

Comment: Can you give an example with 2 users and expected output, please

Comment: @cyadvert the list of IDs is for rows that belong to multiple users. In the case where more than one of the IDs belongs to a single user, I want to return the row with the ID that appears first in the list, excluding the other rows.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Got it. Challenging.... I'll try to do something. Will post if found a solution. There might be multiple subqueries needed. each per user :(

Comment: @Strawberry. Sorry, I'm rather new here... In that case I'll wait for the answer. I'm interested

Comment: @Strawberry if you know a duplicate question, please feel free to link to it. I'm looking through the related questions and can't find an answer to my question.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not looking for the maximum of anything, though?

Comment: @Strawberry You lost me. I've looked at the page, but how am I looking for a minimum of something? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Strawberry `i.e the row with the minimum id` I think you're misunderstanding my question. I don't want to get the minimum ID's in the list, I want to get the one's that appear first for each user. In the example list I gave `2,1,3,6` I said row with ID `2` should be returned. That's not a minimum value, it's what appears fist in the list.

Comment: Ah, right. See how proper DDLs would have helped. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I suggest:

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN (
SELECT t.user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.id ORDER BY FIELD(t.id, 2,1,3,6)),',', 1) AS firstRowPerUser 
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.id IN (2,1,3,6)
GROUP BY t.user_id) tRes ON Table1.id=tRes.firstRowPerUser;
```

Use subquery with `GROUP BY`, `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get get list of users and id of first record from custom list per user.
Then just `JOIN` the result with initial table.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do a subquery in the WHERE using TOP, something like this:

```
SELECT id, user_id, likes
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM tableids WHERE mytable.userid = userid)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Or if you don't have the userid in the other query just using `TOP` will be ok.

Comment: The question appears to be about MySQL